# Pivotal Cloud Foundry - Deployed Spring Boot App failed to run because of java netsocket(port) permission denied

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, cloud-foundry

so, i tried to deploy spring boot app to a PCF Server. When i deployed it, the logs showed that my application was shut down because it failed to open a tomcat server because there is a java.netsocketexception where it says that permission denied. The tomcat server was fine for a moment (it successfully use the port) but the next moment, it was shut down because there is the permission denied netsocketexception.

the port i tried to use is port 443. i tried to look up to several kinds of problems. one of it said that i need to have root access to be able to use port lower than 1000. the problem is, my other apps, which is eureka server run perfectly even when i use port 443.

the configuration, build-pack, and everything is the same. and it is even deployed on a same pcf platform. so, why can this app failed but the other (eureka server) can use the 443 port.

can anyone tell me for the things i need to check to make sure of the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't try to set the port, you need to let the Java buildpack set the port to be used for you (it will do this based on what the platform tells it). Also, you do not need to configure your app to use HTTPS. Again, the platform will handle all that for you. Stop doing all that, and see what happens or explain why you are trying to do that.

Comment: My buildpack and env config default port is 8080, since i want to deploy my apps in port 443, i set the server.port to 443 in application.yml

Comment: The question i asked is why my other app can deploy in port 443, but not the one i tried to deploy

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you do not want to set `server.port` (I'm a little surprised the Java buildpack didn't just squash your setting). Anyway, as I mentioned above TLS/HTTPS is a gift to you from the platform. It just works and you don't need to do anything specific in your application to support it. Simply map a route to your app & access that route via HTTPS. TLS is terminated by the platform & traffic is routed to your app listening via HTTP on port 8080.

Comment: I have no idea why it worked previously. It's hard to say without more information. It's possible the Java buildpack overwrote your setting, it supplies the port via the `SERVER_PORT` env variable, which should override settings in application.yml (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config which lists the order and location from which Spring Boot loads settings). It's also possible you used a TCP route or internal route, which can work on port 443 but you'd know if you did that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `server.port` configuration from Spring Boot yml / properties configuration. It will by default expose the service to 443 on PCF

Comment: Look at my comment in the post above to see why